# the operation % in Dart return a strange value% work in Dart

Tags: dart

The  var c return 3 but 10/7=1.4285, the rest is 0.4285, operator % has a bug?

```
void main() {
  var a = 10;
  var b = 7;
  var c;
  c = a % b;
  print(c);
}
```

Comment: `%` is a [division remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder#Integer_division), so `10 % 7 == 3`.

Comment: Do this: double c = a%b; c = c - c.truncate();

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation of the `%` operator on `num` in Dart:

> Euclidean modulo operator.
>
> Returns the remainder of the Euclidean division. The Euclidean division of two integers `a` and `b` yields two integers `q` and `r` such that `a == b * q + r` and `0 <= r < b.abs()`.
>
> The Euclidean division is only defined for integers, but can be easily extended to work with doubles. In that case `r` may have a non-integer value, but it still verifies `0 <= r < |b|`.
>
> The sign of the returned value `r` is always positive.
>
> See [remainder](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/num/remainder.html) for the remainder of the truncating division.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/num/operator_modulo.html

Comment: That the magic word , Euclidean , só a found the Euclidian division method in youtube and understand  clear how to use %, thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

The '%' operator returns the remainder left after dividing two numbers. It does not return the decimal part. For example:

10 / 7

```
    1
  ______
7 ) 10
   - 7
  ______
     3
```

So it returns 3 which is what remains after dividing 10 by 7 without any decimals.
10 / 7 = 1 3/7

What you want to do can be accomplished like this:

```
var floatNumber = 12.5523;
var x = floatNumber - floatNumber.truncate();
```

Comment: JazakalAllah  dear